# Spatial discretization of the PDE $\partial_tu=\nabla\cdot\kappa(t,\nabla u)\nabla u$ for image processing

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, image-processing, parabolic-pde

The question is basically in the title. I want to evolve an image $u_0$ (i.e. a $n_1\times n_2$ resolution set of discrete values in $[0,1)$, which is a discrete function on $\{0,\ldots,n_1-1\}\times\{0,\ldots,n_2-1\}$) by the PDE $$\partial_tu=\nabla\cdot\kappa(t,\nabla u)\nabla u\tag1$$ with Neumann boundary conditions. $\kappa$ is real-valued. I want to simulate $(1)$ using the Euler scheme together with a spatial discretization of the space derivatives.

Now, my problem is that there are various possibility how the spatial derivatives could be approximated by forward, backward or central finite differences. For the boundary condition as well. Since we are working with discrete images, I really wonder which of these I should use and which spacing (probably $1$?) I should use.

I mostly worry about stability. I think a bad scheme might explode, even though it should not. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I found the 2003 paper "Numerical Computation of Discrete Differential Operators on Non-Uniform Grids" by Sukumar and Bolander to be very helpful on a very similar problem using a non-Cartesian grid. See Section 3.1.

Comment: @JohnBarber Thank you for the suggestion. I've taken a look, but it seems like it is more on finite-elements. My space is simply $[0,1)^2$ and a discretization into a grid with cells is appropriate for me. I've asked a separate question to describe what my actual problem with the existing schemes is. Maybe you can take a look: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4888154/47771