# Numerical solution of Perona-Malik equation: How to handle the boundary properly?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, image-processing, parabolic-pde

In the paper [Perona-Malik equation and its numerical properties](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6291.pdf), the following PDE is considered:

[image]

The $u_0$ I'm (and so is the author) interested in is given by an image and hence decomposes into pixels. The author is proposing the following scheme for a numerical solution:

[image]

This is just an example of many similar schemes you can find to solve (1.6). However, no matter in which reference I look, it is never explained how we deal with $i,j$ corresponding to boundary pixels. Say the image is of resolution $n_1\times n_2$. What do we do for $i\in\{0,n_1-1\}$ or $j\in\{0,n_2-1\}$? If you take a close look to (2.1), you see that even $u_{i+2,\:j}$ and $u_{i,\:j+2}$ are accessed. So, in fact, the formula (2.1) is only clear for me for pixels which are at least 2 pixels away from the border.

I'm also not 100% sure about the Neumann boundary. The normal derivative on $\Omega=[0,1)^2$ (which is the $\Omega$ I'm assuming to be in place here) is clearly simple. Depending on the boundary (top, left, bottom, right) it should simply mean that $u_{n_1,\:j}=u_{n_1-2,\:j}$ for all $j\in\{0,\ldots,n_2-1\}$ for example. But what do we do at the corners where theoretically more than one boundary part is "active"?

Comment: if the final solution is sufficiently regular, say $C^3$, and depends on the domain continuously, then it probably won't cause an issue at a corner (through a posterior error estimate), you can either assign that point to its nearby edge or use the average normal direction.  Usually, the corner issue will occur when the limiting solution diverges from the true one as the domain is approximated by its polygon approximations.

Comment: @Yimin What I understood from your comment is that it doesn't matter how we set the corners, since all options should end up essentially the same as long as enough regularity can be assumed. But can you also tell me how (2.1) deals with border pixels? There are indices involved which actually go 2 pixels beyond the boundary.

Comment: at the boundary, the gradient can be replaced by either forward or backward difference, your central difference will not be able to work there. Unless you use the ghost points outside the domain, the values of the ghost points can be obtained by the Neumann boundary condition.